# Understanding react-router transition animation

Tags: react-router

In this [example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/animations/app.js) I do not understand Why do we need StaticContainer and previousPathname in state. If someone could explain what they do, would be great. I tried to find an explanation on the web, but due to recent major update of react-router it is just impossible. Looked at documentation and still no clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are to keep the `<Link>` elements in the `<Page1>` and `<Page2>` elements from reflecting the new route. If you want to see how things look without the `<StaticContainer>`, try running the example against the 1.0.0-rc3 release.

The logic there specifically is to set `shouldUpdate` to `false` on `StaticContainer` before rendering the updated child, which will effectively "freeze" the transitioning-out element.

Comment: So it is used to freeze the component we are transitioning from?

Comment: Exactly - otherwise the links would change their active state to reflect the new location, which we don't want.